# Display lastName in application after retrieve value key in token Swift 4

Tags: ios, json, swift, token

I have another problem after my previous post.

i want to display lastname in application after i retrieve in value of token. here is my code to get value of lastname in token

```
// request = url of API 
// token = I have already recovered the value of the token
request.addValue("Bearer \(token!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        //get information in token
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]
                    let sub = json["sub"] as! [String: AnyObject]
                    // get value of lastName
                    let lastName = sub["lastname"] as! String

            } catch {
                print("error")   
            }
            }.resume()
```

and now I want to display the lastname in the application

```
    let headerMenu = HPMenuHeaderViewModel.init(lastName: "display lastname here..")
// display table view and information of user like lastname
    let tableViewModel = HPMenuViewModel(titlePage: "Menu", array: arrayCellModel, headerMenuViewModel: headerMenu)
    self.tableViewModel = tableViewModel
```

Can you Help Me please !

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using Closures.

```
 func loadMemberProfil(completion: ((_ sub : [String: AnyObject]) -> Void)?) {
        let token = HPWSLoginManager.shared().saveSuccessResponse.token
        let url = URL(string: "http://51.38.36.76:40/api/v1/profile")
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("Bearer \(token!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        //get information in token
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]
                let sub = json["sub"] as! [String: AnyObject]
        if completion != nil{
            completion(sub)
        }
            } catch {
                print("error")

            }
            }.resume()
    }
```

Then call this method, where you want to set the last name

```
func initTableViewModel() {
    self.loadMemberProfil { (sub) in
        let headerMenu = HPMenuHeaderViewModel.init(firstName: "\(sub["firstname"])", lastName: "\(sub["lastname"])", numberString: "\(sub["internationalFormat"])")
        let tableViewModel = HPMenuViewModel(titlePage: "Menu", array: arrayCellModel, headerMenuViewModel: headerMenu)
        self.tableViewModel = tableViewModel
    }

}
```

Comment: I do not understand your logic very well and what does it mean SkinToneAnimation? and i want display  **let headerMenu = HPMenuHeaderViewModel.init(lastName: "value of lastname here..")**

Comment: SkinToneAnimation is the class,  where I have the function "hitApi(completion: ((_ lastName : String) -> Void)?)". Could you tell me where you are hitting the api and where exactly you want to display Last name.

Comment: I re-explained my problems

Comment: great thanks, I have edited my answer. Please check it and let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: how to call **func loadMemberProfil(completion: ((_ sub : [String: AnyObject]) -> Void)?)** in **viewDidLoad** because he is not recognized in the function **func initTableViewModel()**

Comment: I am really sorry but I did'nt get your point. You can call func initTableViewModel() in viewDidLoad. Or you can call func loadMemberProfil(completion: ((_ sub : [String: AnyObject]) -> Void)?) In viewDidLoad and call func initTableViewModel() from success like this :-

Comment: func viewDidLoad() { self.loadMemberProfil { (sub) in let headerMenu = HPMenuHeaderViewModel.init(firstName: "\(sub["firstname"])", lastName: "\(sub["lastname"])", numberString: "\(sub["internationalFormat"])") let tableViewModel = HPMenuViewModel(titlePage: "Menu", array: arrayCellModel, headerMenuViewModel: headerMenu) self.tableViewModel = tableViewModel } }

Comment: when I implement function **func loadMemberProfil(completion: ((_ sub : [String: AnyObject]) -> Void)?)** in **viewDidLoad** and call it in **func initTableViewModel()** i have this error **Value of type 'HPMenuViewController' has no member 'loadMemberProfil'**

Comment: please check my screen shot in your solution

Comment: I am not able to get to your problem. It would be better if you could share your complete code with class and funcations.

Answer (score 0):

i have this fonction to get firstname, lastname, number

```
func loadMemberProfil(){
let token = HPWSLoginManager.shared().saveSuccessResponse.token
        let url = URL(string: "http://51.38.36.76:40/api/v1/profile")
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("Bearer \(token!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        //get information in token
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]
                    let sub = json["sub"] as! [String: AnyObject]
                    let firstName = sub["firstname"] as! String
                    let lastName = sub["lastname"] as! String
                    let number = sub["internationalFormat"] as! String     
            } catch {
                print("error")

            }
            }.resume()
}
```

and in viewDidLoad() i want to display in this function

```
func initTableViewModel() {
 let headerMenu = HPMenuHeaderViewModel.init(firstName: "...", lastName: "...", numberString: "...")
        let tableViewModel = HPMenuViewModel(titlePage: "Menu", array: arrayCellModel, headerMenuViewModel: headerMenu)
        self.tableViewModel = tableViewModel
}
```